# Xcode issue building 64-bit app with LibX library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, 64-bit

I'm trying to use libXl for iOS and it is giving me a linker error.
"missing required architecture x86_64"

**I've changed the Architechture to standard** but when I try to build for a 64 bit simulator, it gives me the linker error.

What needs to be changed to fix this error if I don't have the source code for the library?

Comment: If you don't have the source code for the library and the library doesn't have a 64-bit slice, then you can't compile a 64-bit version of your app.

Comment: Is it possible to build a 32 bit version and use it for the 64 bit simulator or device?

Comment: @James Tice: Absolutely- although Xcode will probably select a 32-bit simulator for you when you run it. 64-bit capable devices will happily run 32-bit apps.

Comment: So if I run it as normal will it work fine on 64 bit devices (except as a 32 bit) or do I have to change some settings to make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you don't have the source code for the library and the library doesn't have a 64-bit slice, then you can't compile a 64-bit version of your app. (By the looks of things, even the commercial version of [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) doesn't support 64-bit yet.)

Additionally, you can't mix 32 and 64 bit code/libraries within an app, I'm afraid. (If your app is 32 bit, the OS will load a 32 bit version of UIKit, etc. but that's as far as it goes.)

However, if you simply build your app as 32-bit if will run perfectly fine on 64-bit (i.e.: A7 processor+) devices.